# Use newest file in a directory for include_vars`

Tags: ansible, yaml

I need to set up a default value for the variable the last added file under `../roles/somerole/files/`. However I cant use 'find' module because it try to find path on remote host, not on my local machine. Here's an example.

This is my code block:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Get last added file
      find: 
        paths: "../roles/somerole/files/"
      register: found_files

    - name: Include vars from latest file in above folder
      include_vars: "{{ found_files.files | sort(attribute='mtime',reverse=true) | first }}"
```

And this is an output:

```
[WARNING]: Skipped '../roles/somerole/files/' path due to this access issue: '../roles/somerole/files/' is not a directory
ok: [1.1.1.1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 0,
    "files": [],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "age": null,
            "age_stamp": "mtime",
            "contains": null,
            "depth": null,
            "excludes": null,
            "file_type": "file",
            "follow": false,
            "get_checksum": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "paths": [
                "../roles/somerole/files/"
            ],
            "patterns": [
                "*"
            ],
            "read_whole_file": false,
            "recurse": false,
            "size": null,
            "use_regex": false
        }
    },
    "matched": 0,
    "msg": "Not all paths examined, check warnings for details",
```

Could you please advice how can I get files locally, not on the remote host?

Answer (score 2):

Since the files you are looking for are on the controller, you will need to delegate the `find` task to `localhost` and run it with `run_once: true` so that it is not repeated for every host in your play loop. Moreover, for the above to work, you will need to extract the `path` attribute from your result list.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Get last added file from localhost
      find: 
        paths: "../roles/somerole/files/"
      register: found_files
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Include vars from latest file in above folder
      include_vars: "{{ found_files.files | sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true) | map(attribute='path') | first }}"
```